# React-navigation, how to define required params?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation to define the routes of my application, I have them declared as such:
```
const AppStack = StackNavigator(
  {

```
Home: {
  path: '/',
  screen: Root,
},
Room: {
  path: '/room/:id',
  screen: Room,
},
```

As you can see I'm interesting in declaring one of the routes (/room) with a mandatory id param, but I'm not really sure if this makes it mandatory/required?

Is there a way to declare the necessary params for the route?

Comment: I think you can use propType for the Room route/component & while navigating to that route provide your id in props.